# How do I enable print from only one Ray process in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

I am running a recurrent neural network using Tensorflow, and I am varying several of the network parameters in nested loops. Tensorflow has a progress bar, which is nice, but the print is a total mess when the code is parallelised with Ray. Is it possible to suppress the amount of prints by only letting a single process print, or anything equivalent?

Comment: Could you pass a flag into one of the workers and then only print the progress bar if that flag is true?

Comment: That is how I would do it using MPI in C. I am unsure how I can do this with Ray. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating a bit about how you're using Ray and what you're trying to do, but this is an example that creates 3 actors and prints from only one of them.

```
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, print):
        self.print = print

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            # do work
            if self.print:
                print('step ', i)

foo1 = Foo.remote(True)
foo2 = Foo.remote(False)
foo3 = Foo.remote(False)
foos = [foo1, foo2, foo3]

ray.get([foo.run.remote() for foo in foos])
```

Comment: I like your solution! Then I just need to modify this to suppress automatic print from Tensorflow.